# Вызов константного или не константного метода

Tags: c++, ооп

Предположим есть код:

```
class Example {
public:
    void SomeMetod() {
        cout << "non const method called" << endl;
    }

    void SomeMetod() const {
        cout << "const method called" << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    const Example ex1;
    ex1.SomeMetod();

    Example ex2;
    ex2.SomeMetod();

    return 0;
}
```

Два методы перегруженные по константности. Так как сигнатуры методов одинаковые, почему не возникает неопределенность вызова.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Сигнатуры методов - разные. Константность метода класса является частью его сигнатуры.

> **1.3.20 [defns.signature.member]**
>   **signature**
>   [class member function] name, parameter type list (8.3.5), class of which the function is a member, cv-qualifiers (if any), and ref-qualifier (if any)

В процессе overload resolution константность/неконстантность метода выливается в константность/неконстантность скрытого параметра `this`, наличествующего у каждого нестатического метода класса. Таким образом с точки зрения overload resolution ситуация интерпретируется как

```
// Заменим на обычные функции
void SomeMetod(const Example *this_);
void SomeMetod(Example *this_);

int main()
{
  const Example ex1;
  SomeMetod(&ex1);

  Example ex2;
  SomeMetod(&ex2);
}
```

Никакой неоднозначности тут нет.